# Fail a Scheduled Task When PS Script Fails

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks

I run a PowerShell script using Task Scheduler and my issue is that when that script fails, the scheduled Task does not fail and therefore I do not get notified.

So when I run this script on PowerShell:

```
Add-PsSnapIn VeeamPSSnapIn
$Job = Get-VBRJOB -name "Whatever"
Start-VBRJOB -job $Job
```

I get the following exception:

[image]

However, when I run it using a scheduled task, the task does not fail.

How can I get it to fail when the script fails?

Reason I want it to fail is because when it fails, I get notified by Email. If you have any other way of doing it, like logging an event that can trigger the alert, this would be good too.

I'm using Windows Server 2008 R2.

Thanks,

Comment: You might accept one of the below answers (even your own) to show, that this question is solved.

Answer (score 2):

Do you try to put you code into a try/catch statement ?

```
try
{
  Add-PsSnapIn VeeamPSSnapIn
  $Job = Get-VBRJOB -name "Whatever"
  Start-VBRJOB -job $Job
  $returnCode = 0
}
catch
{
  $message = $_.exception.message
  $returnCode = 1
}

return $returnCode
```

In my case I directly send email from the script with the message.

Comment: Thanks, this should work too, I got mine working so won't be changing it. This is simpler though!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this

```
Add-PsSnapIn VeeamPSSnapIn 
$Job = Get-VBRJOB -name "Type the job name here"
$error.clear() #To make sure I'm checking next statement only
Start-VBRJOB -job $Job
if ($error.count -gt 0) 
{
    Write-EventLog –LogName Application –Source “My Company” –EntryType Error –EventID 1 –Message “Whatever Message You Want"
}
```

Then I used Task Scheduler to send Emails when Error 1 from source "My Company" is logged.
Note: You need to create the events source "My Company" using this command on PowerShell:

```
New-EventLog –LogName Application –Source “My Company”
```

Hope this helps someone.

Ahmad